# Birt row.__rownum not working when sent to function

Tags: birt

Sent row.__rownum to function as index but it didn't work.
It always takes the value for first row.

Is it not correct to send it to a function?

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
row.__rownum
```

with two leading underscores.

Comment: okay, so I have mistyped in the question but in the function I chose from the list  it so it wasn't the issue

Comment: "Not working" is not precise enough. If you want an answer, you have to add some details.